# IMAP server (MS Exchange) returns for UID MOVE and STORE Flags "BAD Command received in Invalid state"

Tags: curl, exchange-server, imap

I searched for the error messsage "BAD Command received in Invalid state.", but I found it only in combination with unsecure logins and not as a respond to a usual command.

These commands are working perfectly:

```
# obtain mail ids
curl -sS --user $imap_login:$imap_pass -X "SEARCH ALL" --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port/INBOX"

# obtain mail content
curl -sS --user $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port/INBOX;UID=$mail_id

# obtain mail folders
curl -sS --user $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port"
# or
curl -sS --user $imap_login:$imap_pass -X 'LIST "" *' --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port"
```

But the following commands fail:

```
# move mail to trash
curl -vsS --user $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port" -X "UID MOVE $mail_id \\Trash"

# flag mail as deleted
curl -vsS --user $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port" -X "STORE $mail_id +Flags \\Deleted"
```

Both return "A003 BAD Command received in Invalid state.":

```
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: xxx
*    start date: 2022-03-07 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2023-04-05 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: xxx
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
< * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
> A001 CAPABILITY
< * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
< A001 OK CAPABILITY completed.
> A002 AUTHENTICATE NTLM xxx
< A002 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
> A003 UID MOVE 1 \Trash
< A003 BAD Command received in Invalid state.
> A004 LOGOUT
< * BYE Microsoft Exchange Server 2016 IMAP4 server signing off.
< A004 OK LOGOUT completed.
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
curl: (21) Quote command returned error
```

What could be my mistake?

Comment: `UID MOVE` and `STORE` are valid in selected state, that is, while you've selected a folder to operate on. You don't select any folder; there's no `SELECT` command in the log.

Comment: You dropped ‘INBOX’ from your URL so it doesn’t know what folder to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

@Max was right. I dropped the /INBOX from the url and by that the IMAP server didn't know which mail in which folder should be moved.

Finally the IMAP server did not support MOVE at all. So I came to this solution:

```
# copy mail to trash
curl -sS --login-options AUTH=NTLM -u $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port/INBOX" -X "COPY $mail_id \"/Gel&APY-schte Elemente\""

# flag mail for deletion
curl -sS --login-options AUTH=NTLM -u $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port/INBOX" -X "STORE $mail_id +FLAGS (\\Deleted)" >/dev/null

# after the loop... (the IMAP server re-assigns mail ids directly after deletion!)
# delete flagged mails
curl -sS --login-options AUTH=NTLM -u $imap_login:$imap_pass --url "imaps://$imap_host:$imap_port/INBOX" -X "EXPUNGE" >/dev/null
```

Note: `--login-options AUTH=NTLM` is needed in recent versions of curl as the default for "user@server" became `AUTH=GSSAPI`.

Comment: According to your logs (see the CAPABILITY response), Exchange does in fact support the MOVE command.

Comment: Yes, that's crazy: It even confirms the movement, but finally nothing has been moved.